# Magento 2: Change links html class in customer account navigation

Tags: magento2, layout, template, xml, customer-account

I'm trying to change the html classes for my customer_account_navigation block.
What I actually want to achieve is to display different icons for every single link.

I tried the following in the `customer_account.xml` but without success:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one instead.
Have it working this way.

```
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">customer-account-navigation-account-link</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Don't forget to clear cache :)